# Nodejs: how to set fake path for files to download

Tags: node.js, express

In my nodejs app I have a static path "/public" which has following structure:

```
-public
    -images
    -js
    -posts
        -2017
            -07
            -08
            -09
```

As you can see I create a folder every year and every month to store files.

Now when I link a file from the view I can see the path **/posts/2017/09/file.txt** and I don't want to show this

Is there a way to set a fake path(maybe with params) in order to hide my folder structure ?

Comment: can you put your code ? Seeing your code, i might be able to help you on creating algorithms

Comment: What type of URL do you want?  How about `/posts?date=2017-09`?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes or replacing 'posts' by 'files' so files?date=2017-09 will point to /posts/2017/09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a url like `/files?date=2017-09`, you could do something this:

```
const path = require('path');

// handle routes like this: /files?date=2017-09
app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
    let date = req.query.date;
    // if no date or if it contains illegal characters, then disallow it
    // this is important to prevent injection of weird paths and ../../ stuff
    if (!date || /[^\d-]/.test(date)) {
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    // I'm not sure what your root path is here, so replace /public with 
    // whatever that is supposed to be
    let file = path.join('/public/posts', date.replace("-", path.sep));
    res.sendFile(file, {dotfiles: "deny"}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).end();
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you so much